# SQL MONTH AVERGE

Tags: sql, oracle, date, time, average

Here is what I got to get the duration of the two.

```
select (TO_TIMESTAMP(s.END, 'hh24:mi:ss') - TO_TIMESTAMP(s.START, 'hh24:mi:ss')) from SESSION s;
```

I am trying to get the average per month. I do have a time dimension that I can refer to using month_name from the table. However, how to I do this? I have tried to use add_months by casting it but got no luck.

Thank you guys.

VARCHAR for all.

```
DATE         START      END        RESULT OF QUERY        AVERAGE PER MONTH
13-FEB-11   16:00:00    18:00:00   +00 02:00:00.000000       ?
02-APR-11   08:30:00    10:30:00   +00 02:00:00.000000
02-APR-11   16:00:00    18:00:00   +00 02:00:00.000000
05-APR-11   08:30:00    10:30:00   +00 02:00:00.000000
05-APR-11   16:00:00    18:00:00   +00 02:00:00.000000
```

Comment: Do you really have separate columns to store the date and time? What are the datatypes of columns `date`,`start` and `end`?

Comment: varchar for all. @GMB and yes. I do have to have it seperate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest turning the scripts to `date`s instead of timestamps. This gives you a numeric result that represents the interval as days, which, unlike an interval, you can average.

If you want the average session duration per month, you can aggregate like so:

```
select 
    trunc(to_date(s.date, 'dd-mon-yy'), 'mm') mnt,
    avg(to_date(s.end, 'hh24:mi:ss') - to_date(t.start, 'hh24:mi:ss')) avg_duration
from session s
group by trunc(to_date(s.date, 'dd-mon-yy'), 'mm')
```

If you want the result as an interval, you can use `numtodsinterval()` on the results of the computation:

```
select 
    trunc(to_date(s.date, 'dd-mon-yy'), 'mm') mnt,
    numtodsinterval(
        avg(to_date(s.end, 'hh24:mi:ss') - to_date(t.start, 'hh24:mi:ss')),
        'day'
    ) avg_interval
from session s
group by trunc(to_date(s.date, 'dd-mon-yy'), 'mm')
```